# Calling a AddIn from another class or AddIn?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I've tried several ways but I can't find anything working. Is there any possibility to call an AddIn from outside? I want to fill a AddIn Combobox when the `OnClick` Event of an AddIn Button is fired, but don't know how to address the Combobox.

Have you any Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Communication between components can be done either directly (you address other addin components with [AddIn.FromID](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001v00000247000000), or using application extensions. The latter is especially useful if you need to share any data or state between multiple components. Extensions are also useful when you need to persist any state in the document.

The SDK includes a good discussion of this exact topic: see [Add-in coding patterns](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Add_in_coding_patterns/0001000000zz000000/).

Comment: +1 Also need to provide an Add method for the combobox, the base class's [Add method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Add_Method/001v000000tp000000/) is protected.