# ArcObjects Add-in - Making distinct add-in components talk to each other

Tags: arcobjects, java, add-in

I'm starting developing with ArcObjects and I'm stuck at trying to make two comboboxes talk to each other. What am I trying to do is changing the contents/selection of *ComboBox B* based on the selection of *ComboBox A*. But so far I don't know how to get the *ComboBox B* instantiation inside *ComboBox A* code.

An example code I found so far use `ICommandBars`, but it needs an `IApplication` reference that ComboBoxes do not receive as parameter in their `initialize()` method. Another example is by using method `findExtensionByCLSID(UID)`, but it also needs an `IApplication` reference.

Can someone give me a hint on how to grab another add-in component informations (such as selected item in ComboBoxes)?

A piece of code I have to try catching a ComboBox instantiation is presented below (this code is inside a combo named *DimCombo*, and tries to pick a *FormaCombo* combo instance to do some work). I guess my problem is at setting the `app` variable, as it is not given in combos initialization method.

```
public void getFormaCombo(){
    try{
        UID pUID = new UID();
        pUID.setValue("br.mil.eb.dsg.arctools.formacombo");
        formaCombo = (FormaCombo) app.findExtensionByCLSID(pUID);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Note**: `br.mil.eb.dsgtools.formacombo` is the ID of the desired combo instance (set in config.xml). I'm using Java, but hints can be in any language.

---

**Edit**

Apparently I found a way to grab ComboBoxes from within a `Tool` code. Solution is a code similar to the previous one, but it is now included inside the desired ComboBox implementation. Client tool should invoke this method to fetch the desired combo's instance.

```
public static DimCombo getExtension() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    if(s_extension == null){
        UID pUID = new UID();
        pUID.setValue("br.mil.eb.dsg.arctools.dimcombo");
        app.findExtensionByCLSID(pUID);
    }
    return s_extension;
}
```

Tool components need to do something like:

```
DimCombo combo = DimCombo.getExtension();
```

And then ComboBox methods are made available (like `getSelected()`).

But I am still with no solutions on making another ComboBox call the `getExtension()` like above. It gives a null pointer exception exactly at the above line.

So I still need some more help.

Comment: Does this answer help?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/7517/43  The link to the add-in coding patterns seems informative.

Comment: In fact, it was not so helpful. I've created an extension to do some work, but I still don't know how to call the ComboBox from within that extension.

Comment: Richard, your hint was of a little help, though. ComboBoxes do not initialize with the `IApplication` reference, so I've added an extension just to get it. My ComboBoxes now grab the reference from the extension, and the `findExtensionByCLSID(pUID)` can be used.

Comment: Richard, I finally found the solution using extensions! Will post the solution right now.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to workaround the problem, mainly using Richard's suggestion (comment in my original post).

So, for anyone looking for a solution to a problem like mine, here is the solution that worked for me.

---

ComboBoxes can't communicate directly with each other. Instead, it should be used an *Application Extension* addin. Extensions can communicate with any addin component inside the same project, considering that each component provides a method to retrieve its instance.

Using my problem as an example, let's take a look at the instance retrieval method for a ComboBox named *FormaCombo*:

```
public static FormaCombo getExtension() throws Exception{
    if(s_extension == null){
            UID pUID = new UID();
            pUID.setValue("br.mil.eb.dsg.arctools.formacombo");
            app.findExtensionByCLSID(pUID);
    }
    return s_extension;
}
```

(`s_extension` is a `FormaCombo` variable, declared at the beginning of class implementation.)

Take a look at `app.findExtensionByCLSID(pUID)`. Here, `app` is a `IApplication` reference that ComboBoxes do not receive at their initialization methods. But since extensions do, we can get this reference from the extension and use inside the ComboBox, like this:

```
@Override
public void initialize() {
    s_extension = this;
    try{
        GabExtension gabExt = GabExtension.getExtension();
        FormaCombo.app = gabExt.appl;
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}
```

(`GabExtension` is the name of my extension. It also have the `getExtension()` method like the ComboBox.)

Some remarks here:

- Since components are singletons, `getExtension()` methods are static. Thus, `app` variables should also be static for every component (including the extension), in order to be used inside this method.
- To pick `app` reference from the extension, it shouldn't be static. But it has to be static for the reason above. To solve this paradox, simply declare another `IApplication` variable, non-static, inside the extension, that picks the same value (`IApplication appl = app` - easy like that), and use this one. In my example code, *FormaCombo* has an `IApplication` variable named `app`, static, that gets the same value of `appl`, non-static, from the extension.

Now let's say we have a ComboBox named *DimCombo* (I'm using the names for my particular project) that has to do some work inside *FormaCombo*. To establish communication, every request should be passed to the extension, and from that to the other ComboBox. So, if we want to add a new item to *FormaCombo* based on the selection in *DimCombo*, this should do the trick:

```
public void onSelChange(int cookie){
    try {
        curSelect = cookie;
        Criterio crit = new Criterio();
        for(Criterio c: criterios){
            if(c.getIndex() == curSelect){
                crit = c;
                break;
            }
        }

        gabExt.formaComboClear();
        int const_circ = gabExt.addFormaComboItem("Circulo");
        gabExt.setFormaComboConstants(1, const_circ);
        if(crit.getTipo() == 2){
            gabExt.setFormaComboConstants(2, gabExt.addFormaComboItem("Quadrado"));
        }
        gabExt.setFormaComboCirculo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Code is for my project, so let's focus on what is relevant here.

Note the `gabExt.formaComboClear()`, `gabExt.addFormaComboItem("Circulo") and other similar methods. All of them do some work in ComboBox *FormaCombo* - in fact, it **asks the extension to do some job in the destination ComboBox**.

Let's see how `gabExt.formaComboClear()` works:

```
public void formaComboClear(){
    try{
        formaCombo = FormaCombo.getExtension();
        formaCombo.clear();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you might have seen, it has nothing special; it just calls the *FormaCombo* `clear()` method. So why not doing this direcly from the other ComboBox? Because ArcObjects won't let you. This is the way to make things happen.

For the other methods, the behavior is similar.

---

**Conclusion**

If you want to make two addin components talk to each other, consider including an application extension addin to intermediate calls between them. Also, remember to include a `getExtension()` method similar to the example provided here, so the extension could find the components at runtime.